# You will have to pray!

Tags: word, treasure-hunt

This riddle is so easy that I already have created another one. Just in case.
Anyway, please avoid wild guesses.

For sure I am queer
and out of place
Are you still here?
Go start the chase

But always remember
in the first place
stacks are amazing
but not a maze

I'm in the beginning
as well as the end
And always traceable
no matter what I pretend

I really am curious
about who will find
the animate being
that hides behind

The solution is here

> No, it is not. One might call it far-fetched.

---

Here is also a real hint

> You will find only one of my kind.

Comment: Ouroboros sometimes thought of as the self devouring but actually self creating

Comment: Is this a programming riddle? Is the answer a singleton: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: The hardest part of these puzzles is determining which words are actually relevant, and which are just included to make things rhyme. ;)

Comment: many of the answers seem to come from bored programmers browsing stackoverflow who saw this link in the "trending questions" list

Comment: Perhaps a logo?

Comment: it seems like a empty set. Only one of its kind, nothing in the beginning and nothing in the end.

Comment: This question is unsuitable for Stack Exchange because its intended answer depends on external elements, namely, the author's profile and recent activity, that won't make sense in a few days or on another site. It is also [off-topic because it has no well-defined answer](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1254).

Comment: Oh, so you didn't manage to solve it? The next one will be very easy don't worry!

Comment: Hi @Gilles, I agree this is a contentious question. The author indicated he wasn't going to do this style any more. It _is_ clever, but you're right about how it doesn't really suit the normal SE format. I also hope you don't let this popular but odd question tarnish your perception of _all_ the popular content on Puzzling.

Comment: Hey avi, have a look at *my* 'pray' riddle - d'alar'cop has solved it and I'm hiding from the lynch mob too!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> The answer is "cat."
>
> *For sure I am queer and out of place. Are you still here? Go start the chase*
>  
> This means that the answer is not here, on this page. After some looking around, I ended up on avigrail's user page, finding this:
>  
>  Well done! If you are looking for something
>  *out of place*
>  you are on the right track here.
>  
>  Next up:
>  
>  *But always remember in the first place stacks are amazing but not a
>  maze*
>  
>  This led me to look around on Stack Exchange, eventually ending up on avigrail's network profile mostly by chance. There I found:
>  Well done! Almost there.
>  
>  Next part of the riddle:
>  
>  *I'm in the beginning as well as the end And always traceable no matter
>  what I pretend*
>  
>  I originally thought this referred to tags, but now I'm pretty sure it refers to edits. Reason being, the answer is [in an edit that avigrail made yesterday](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/4247/revisions).
>  
>  *I really am curious about who will find the animate being that hides
>  behind*
>  
>  Curiosity killed the cat, they say.

---

> FYI I included some other small things here (very small actually). Those were not to be the main hints.
>
> The second meaning for "in the end" is that this riddle of course includes the solution, too. Technically, this post also is *the end* (for now :p). 
>
> *The solution is here - No it is not*. No further explanation. Same with *far-fetched*.
>
> *You will **find** only one of my kind* - is pretty interesting because by **finding** (CRTL + F) the word "cat" could be found only once on this page. By now, several answers to this questions have added some cats of course. Anyway you will most likey *find* "cat" but no dog, cow, rabbit, etc. In other words the cat is the only kind of animal around.
>
> *And always traceable, no matter what I pretend* also means, that the solution was hidden in a spoiler and therefore pretended to be invisible/untraceable. Hilarious side effect: the **cat** hides until you move your **mouse** close to it.

Comment: always traceable refers to the fact that avi cannot delete it

Comment: "in the first place"...
that was avi's first question..
"at the end"... the edit occurs at the end

Comment: nicely done my friend. In fact this is the answer. I will accept it even if you missed some very little details around ;)

Comment: in the title "have to pray"... refers to "prey" - we are going hunting

Comment: @avigrail I thought of this.. I asked you "is it a pet?" :p

Comment: @avigrail I must confess this was not fun. It was more like an "amazing race"

Comment: @d'alar'cop Excellent catch! My original justification for "beginning" and "end" was a bit of a stretch. So it was sort of a "I don't quite get that part but here's the answer anyway" type of deal. The always traceable line was what did it for me.

Comment: maybe it got lost between other messages :( I really feel bad now, because I didnt see it! I also expected this to be not one of your favs.

Comment: @avigrail Oh well, at least it was interesting and creative :p

Comment: Can't say I like it. But well done, @txteclipse!

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Answer (score 21):

Are you

> deoxyribonucleic acid? 
> "AND" out of place = DNA.
> DNA is both in"**be**gi**n**ning" and "**end**", if you turn e's to form a's and flip b's to form d's.
> DNA molecules are held together by "[pi - stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacking_(chemistry))".
> DNA is traceable (e.g. in forensic cases).
> DNA encodes for animate beings.
> The clue you will only find one of my kind relates to the fact that each being has a unique DNA sequence.

Comment: I will upvote this one for its effort and originality. It is not my solution tho. I have to point this out: "and" out of place = "DNA" is so damn brilliant!

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Comment: @Gilles, I don't agree, so I have chosen to keep it as is.  I also cannot click your link because it is apparently untrusted without a https.  Are you trying to track me mate?

Comment: That exchange seemed a bit schizophrenic until I realized that there were 2 different accounts with the display name "Gilles" :)

Answer (score 6):

> Time
>  its considered as a fourth dimension thats kinda queer as we cant comprehend 4d objects
>  Time stacks are a name given to photos which show lots of time in one image there amazing
>  but they are no maze
>  we measure time trace it back through history, make futuristic predictions and so forth
>  the animate being is yourself in the future if you were to look through time. Are you curios to see your future self.

Comment: You guys are amazing! This solution is incredibly nice but unfortunately not the answer to my riddle.

Comment: dam! I genuinly thought I had finally cracked one of yours

Comment: I admit your solution fits in quite well for some of the lines. For example, time always runs so you better "start the chase". Also time is in the beginning and the end. The idea with the stacks on photos is very nice, too.

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Comment: This Gilles knows how to copy paste!

Answer (score 3):

> memory

reasons for my answer:

> For sure I am queer, - *we hardly remember something, but easily remember something, too.* 
>  and out of place, - *it can't be seen* 
>  Are you still here? - *sometimes we forgot something shortly*
>  Go start the chase - *we sometime want to remember things we forgot*
>  But always remember, in the first place, stacks are amazing, but not a maze - *we get more memory as we grow up, it will keep "stacking" until the end* 
>  I'm in the beginning, as well as the end - *we have memory since we born, until we die*
>  And always traceable, no matter what I pretend - *we can remember something when we saw/touch/smell specific item or hear specific word. Even when you have amnesia*
> I really am curious, about who will find, the animate being, that hides behind - *we can rewind what we have done, and find something back*

another answer (for fun):

> a troll/people who make fun of you whatever you did, they are in everywhere, you can trace them, but barely can do things to them

Comment: It is a awesome answer but we dont create memories at the beginning, we dont have the brain capacity untill around 3 years of age. Upvote still in order :)

Comment: @Oblongamous Source for that claim? [Wikipedia disagrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory#Memory_in_infancy), and so do my experiences as a parent ;)

Comment: <a rel="http://www.webmd.com/children/news/20110511/when-do-kids-form-their-first-memories">WebMD</a> although maybe 3 years old is a little outdated it does imply that for at least a year our limbic system just isnt up to scratch. If my children say they remember me first attempting to change their nappy, my face would be all shades of red :D

Comment: although I could be slicing apart habits and memory as different entities, thats maybe a question for a different stack.

Comment: http://www.webmd.com/children/news/20110511/when-do-kids-form-their-first-memories

Comment: @Geobits I always get a kick out of asking my 3-year old, "Remember when you were born?" and when they answer affirmatively hearing how they try to describe what it was like.  (Stuff like, "I came out of mommy's tummy!")

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Answer (score 3):

> the shadow

Why?

> It is out of place of where the original object it reflects, stacks of things don't affect it, it is a simple hard object, it appears when the light comes on, all the way till it dies down, and it does not matter what it looks like, you can always see trace it... The animate that hides behind? could be symbolic to: the object that it reflects

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Comment: But everything you can put in an answer for a puzzle. .. is a spoiler!

Comment: Why would you scroll down to read the answers if not to read the answers? How can I decide whether your answer would be interesting to read if the only thing I know about it is that it contains “Why?” in the middle?

Comment: This isnt how puzzles work, maybe stachexchange isn't the perfect platform for it, but ppl are not supposed to see answers unless they formed their own answer, hiding stuff is for them not to see by mistake, but they open spoilers based on comments and ratings

Answer (score 2):

Here's my thought:

> The answer is **the null pointer**, as in C and C-like languages.
>
> - Normally it's not supposed to appear in programs, thus "out of place" and needing to be "chased".
> - In some languages like C, it points to the start of memory (the zero address), but is often used to signal the end of a data structure with indeterminate length, like strings and "stacks".
> - Many compilers and runtimes "pretend" that the null pointer points to nothing (and signal its use as an error), because to do otherwise would open up major potential for security bugs, but (assuming that it points to zero, which is true for many languages but not all of them), technically it *could* point to something useful if it were allowed to be "traced".

Comment: Another beautiful solution that is completly wrong.

Comment: I know it's not the site for this, but it's perfectly fine to use null in programs!

Comment: As long as you're using it carefully and deliberately, yes. The problem with null pointers is that they're very easy to use accidentally, and the fact that you're using them at all isn't always obvious. That's where the problems begin.

Answer (score 2):

If the riddle is computer related :

> An IP adress

Because :

> Queer = not understandable by the average user, 
>  Start the chase = find the shortest way to the next IP, 
>  Stacks relate to the complexity of Internet routes, 
>  Beginning and end = Both client and server, 
>  Always traceable (even though it can be very difficult), 
>  Animate being = human or machine on either side, 
>  One of a kind

It doesn't seem like it fits everything but it's my best guess

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Answer (score 1):

Your hint brings to mind

> a fingerprint, and this connects well with the "beginning" and "end", as they are at the ends of your fingers, and stick with you from the beginning and end of your life. They look rather like a "maze"?? are literally traceable and traceable for tracking crimes etc. and humans are behind them and each are unique?! also you touch them together when you pray hahahah

idk im new here hi

Comment: A warm welcome to you! Those are some nice ideas for sure. Do they really fit everywhere?

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Answer (score 1):

> A road

seems to fit everything except the last verse and the hint.

> It's 'out of place' because it leads out of the place where it begins. 'Go start the chase' - chasing along the road. 'Not a maze' - it's a straight road. 'I'm in the beginning as well as the end' - both ends of the road are part of it. It's 'always traceable' because it appears on a map.

Probably not the right answer though, since it has nothing to do with 'stacks' or an 'animate being' and it's not 'the only one of its kind'!

Answer (score 1):

> i am the beginning, i am the end... makes me think of a circle
>  stacks are amazing... maybe i am taking this too literally
>
>  could it be... a circular queue?
>  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer
>
>  they sure are queer... yet, always traceable...

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Answer (score 0):

> Pokemon

Pokemon are conventionally odd entities (Queer)
Whilst in the pokeball they see nothing (Are you still here?)
Gotta catch em all (The chase)
Ash' Pikachu was with him from the beginning and always will be his pokemon (In the first place)
Pokemon evolve from one stage to another so the initial one is still the end one, but evolved (I'm in the beginning as well as the end, and always traceable)
Pokemon are curious creatures (I really am curious)
You have to hunt to find them in long grass or elsewhere etc. (About who will find, the animate being, that hides behind)
Pokemon are animate beings

*You said no wild guesses, but they can be tamed!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here so my spoiler tag could be a bit messy, forgive me.

Could the answer be:

> Fossils/bones 
>  
>  - It is queer to see fossils (bones) in the ground or in rocks where they could be considered out of place
>
>  - Paleontologists chase after fossils
>
>  - Stacks are geological formations which can be made of limestone, sometimes containing fossils, i.e the jurassic coast. they are pretty amazing to look at but they are not a maze
>
>  - They are there at the beginning , when a vertebrate is born and they remain at the end after the flesh has decomposed
>
>  - They are tracable through carbon dating and genetic testing, i suppose, no matter how they are hidden 
>
>  - You can trace bones to the animal that they once supported
>
>  - I also assume that no two bones are the same

It could also be:

> cloth

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Answer (score -1):

I want to say

> Life
>
> - It is technically out of place in the universe, where non-life is the vast majority.
> - Stacks, i.e., lots of life/lives is better than a little, I suppose.
> - Beginning and end are merely a metter of timeframe, lives are traceable whether people want it or not.
> - And behind every life there's something animate.
> - And everyone only has one (cats go away!).

but it doesn't really fit the bill in all aspects..

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.