# Every second is a waste of time

Tags: riddle, word

```
Ok, as you might have expected I secretly implemented 
many hints for you. This time I want you to answer with this:

a unique, selfmade picture with nothing else but the
solution on it. Please use colors with contrast to the
background color (for obvious reasons, I appreciate).

But first you should put your smart phone away and read!
Go ahead and look for the incredibly well hidden
connection between the hints. Give me a detailed and plain 
description of it and you will, I am absolutely sure,
be the winner! I can't wait to see how you guys try to
find the final clue to this, of course, very easy riddle.

Good luck ladies and gentlemen. 
For sure, this is the easiest riddle I have ever seen!
```

The Doll, the Owl, the Dwarf and the Bear
standing on a cabinet they were
Looking down on their cruel fate
they already hung their heads
You will try to kill them all
but one will elude your threats
They cannot see who'll be the one
they are as far as can be
But maybe you can tell them soon
so they can die peacefully
[image: Oh! You just found a mirror on the cabinet.]

Comment: <noClue>Uploading riddles via mobile is not recommended!</noClue>

Comment: Is it actually supposed to be easy, or do you just say that to annoy people? Cyanide ... :-)

Comment: Well, I said it twice. It must be the truth then!

Comment: That sad tag looks extremely fishy... (Uploaded from my smart phone)

Comment: I figured it out! It's about killing them, right? Well, the second letter in each name spells Owwe! The bear escapes because the letter doesn't fit! Genius!

Comment: This sounds a bit too easy doesn't it?

Comment: Is this one going to be as bad as the [one-of-a-kind cat?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/are-you-clever-enough-you-will-have-to-pray)

Comment: I'd not call it bad. Let's agree on easy.

Comment: Can those dolls stand on the cabinet while being hung at the same time? Hanging them with feets on the floor? Is that why they didn't die (yet)? Hmm... much questions, so wow.

Comment: "easiest riddle..." oh dear

Comment: 'Ladies and gentleman': clue or typo?

Comment: @avigrail I really appreciate the creativity, but some of your hidden hints are likely to be unwittingly destroyed.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Maybe those are not hints then? Maybe they are.

Comment: @avigrail - So now that we've solved the riddle, what was all that about mobiles??

Comment: Looking at the riddle with your mobile may change the break of the lines. As a following one wont find the object.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. See you over at the new cyanide :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IT IS THE:

> DOLL

Who avoids our threats.

There was something hidden in the:

> Markup... a mirror (take a look)

If you:

> Reflect all the names of the stuffed animals, the Doll is the only one who isn't "killed". This means that "Doll" is the only words that isn't mangled when you reflect the name on the horizontal axis.

### Let's analyse the clues further:

The title is "Every second is a waste of time".

Read every second line of the preface:

> Ok, as you might have expected I secretly implemented 
>  a unique, selfmade picture with nothing else but the
>  background color (for obvious reasons, I appreciate).
>  Go ahead and look for the incredibly well hidden
>  description of it and you will, I am absolutely sure,
>  find the final clue to this, of course, very easy riddle.
>  
>  For sure, this is the easiest riddle I have ever seen!

---

**courtesy of rand al'thor**

The last line of the secret message is just avigrail being infuriating ( :-) ), but the rest gives us a new message. Now

> click on the button to edit the question - look into HTML/Markdown,

and we find, as expected,

> a link to a picture with nothing else but the background colour,

but also

> a hidden message saying "Oh! You just found a mirror on the cabinet."

---

Now the clues themselves:

The Doll, the Owl, the Dwarf and the Bear

> These are main objects of the riddle. It seems clear that they will be significant

standing on a cabinet they were

> They are all lined up together

Looking down on their cruel fate. they already hung their heads

> They are all "looking down" - i.e. in the same direction. This is the signal for horizontal reflection.

You will try to kill them all
but one will elude your threats

> You will mangle them somehow (seems obvious since we have a mirror). BUT "one will elude our threats" (how mysterious). This refers to the fact that "Doll" is the only one of the 4 names of the toys that isn't mangled by the mirror reflection.

They cannot see who'll be the one
they are as far as can be
But maybe you can tell them soon
so they can die peacefully

> This is just a poetic way to emphatically signal that the final answer will be one of the animals - i.e. that is what we are supposed to identify.

Let the cyanide lift :D

Comment: I'll be your second!

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

> Mirror.

### Speculation

> The mirror is the only connection between the hints and the given poem. At this point I'm suspecting the entire poem is a red herring and you are supposed to find the answer at the first part of the text.

### Use of the Hints

> Skip one line each in the first part of the post:
> "Ok, as you might have expected I secretly implemented  a unique,
> selfmade picture with nothing else but the background color (for
> obvious reasons, I appreciate). Go ahead and look for the incredibly
> well hidden description of it and you will, I am absolutely sure, find
> the final clue to this, of course, very easy riddle. For sure, this is
> the easiest riddle I have ever seen!"

### Final clue

> Dig into the HTML (or markdown) for the image with "nothing but the background color". Its caption reads: "Oh! You just found a mirror on the cabinet".

Comment: I'm impressed! But that's only half of it.

Comment: Oh, top answer beat me to it.

Comment: @Ozy there's a little more to it. Well done finding avi's hidden clue :)

Answer (score 1):

**Guess**

> Whitespace

**Justification 1**

> "Ok, as you might have expected I secretly implemented many hints for you." This hint that there are other clues elsewhere, so take a look at the markdown of the post, you will see comments that will further justify my answer.

**Justification 2**

> "A unique, selfmade picture with nothing else but the solution on it. Please use colors with contrast to the background color." I'm thinking the picture found in the comments will justify this. Even if the background color is white, and font color is black, it will still be a plain white image.

**Justification 3**

> "Go ahead and look for the incredibly well hidden connection between the hints." Well, in the markdown, there are huge amount of whitespace connecting the hints.

**Justification 4**

> "Give me a detailed and plain description of it and you will, I am absolutely sure, be the winner!"

**Justification 5**

> "Give me a detailed and plain description of it and you will, I am absolutely sure, be the winner!" The description I gave is indeed detailed enough, and plain enough (pun intented I guess).

**Justification 6**

> In the poem, the first verse state that there are Doll, Owl, Dwaft and Bear. If you look carefully at your keyboard, Owl escape being above the keyboard. So when they look down on their cruel fate, Owl shall elude its threats.

That say, there are just some part of the hint and poem that I cannot wrap my head around with.

Comment: That's not the correct answer and far from my solution. You better use what you've found.

Answer (score 0):

> The Wind. To tell them is to speak, to speak is to blow, all will fall because the owl is a jerk and wont help.

---

> [image].

Comment: The owl is not a jerk! Nice picture :)