# Riddle... pray that this is the last one

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Stop worshipping me!
Away! you flea!
I'll stomp you with my boots,
You know I'll accept any substitutes,
At first, I change you,
Then I begin to arrange you,
And finally I end your precious heartbeat!

Who is yelling at you?

*As usual, please explain all steps in deriving an answer :)*

Comment: easy. 11 more to go ...

Comment: @avigrail see you later avi :)

Comment: What does '11 more to go' mean??? @avigrail - have you solved it already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet again it's

> a cat.

*Stop worshipping me! 

Away! you flea!*

> The cat is telling us, the riddlers of Stackexchange, to stop writing riddles about it :-p Also, in former times, Egyptians worshipped cats. Cats get and surely hate fleas :D

*I'll stomp you with my boots,*

> This is a reference to [Puss in Boots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puss_in_Boots).

*You know I'll accept any substitutes,*

> Cats are not known for loyalty.

*At first, I change you, 

 Then I begin to arrange you, 

 And finally I end your precious heartbeat!*

> C is the *first* letter in *change*; *then* the letter A *begin*s the word *arrange*, and *finally* the letter T *end*s the word *heartbeat* - spelling out CAT.

The title is also a hint, since two riddles with [similar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/are-you-clever-enough-you-will-have-to-pray?rq=1) [titles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5141/riddle-pray-you-can-find-the-word?rq=1) have both had the same solution.

Comment: Now edited! You need to come up with some ideas of your own, @d'alar'cop :-p

Comment: ....well done! :D