# I'll lick you, I'm neat

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'll lick you, I'm neat
>   Nestled down at your feet
>   Softly purring away
>
> I'm fearsome, I roar
>   I'm on guard while you snore
>   Watching shadows at play
>
> But best you beware
>   Lest you treat me with care
>   You may trip a primitive rage
>
> I'll lash out in a beat
>   And thrash all within reach
>   You'll wish I'd not slipped from my cage

---

I'll lick you, I'm neat
To guess me's a treat
I know I'll warm your heart

But if you've come late
Well, comment your hate
Then down-arrow, 'x' and depart

---

Hint 1:

> Don't guess the obvious.

Hint 2:

> Guess the slightly less obvious.

Hint 3:

> The downvote button is on the left there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you ...

> A campfire

I'll lick you, I'm neat

> tongues of flame

Nestled down at your feet

> putting your feet up by the fire; campfires are on the ground by your feet

Softly purring away

> poetic license for the quiet sizzlecracklepop of a low banked fire

I'm fearsome, I roar

> put some ready flammables on a fire and it roars up quite fearsomely

I'm on guard while you snore

> campfires ward away animals from your campsite, while you sleep

Watching shadows at play

> flames cast dancing shadows

But best you beware
Lest you treat me with care
You may trip a primitive rage

> an out of control fire is a primitive force of nature, so fires must always be carefully tended.

I'll lash out in a beat
And thrash all within reach

> They can get out of control very quickly, and burn up everything in reach.

You'll wish I'd not slipped from my cage

> indeed. forest fires are serious business!

I'll lick you, I'm neat
To guess me's a treat
I know I'll warm your heart

> not really part of the riddle, as it's not in the block; but still, "warm" is a final clue

But if you've come late
Well, comment your hate
Then down-arrow, 'x' and depart

> also not part of the riddle.  this just completes the poem, with some humorous snark.

---

Hint 1:

> *Don't guess the obvious.*
>  Which would be a cat.  I'm not guessing that.

Hint 2:

> *Guess the slightly less obvious.*
>  Which I hope I just did.

Hint 3:

> *The downvote button is on the left there.*
>  Don't do it!

Comment: I am. For exactly every reason you said. I think you broke it down perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious solution to the first section (4 verses) is

> CAT (neat, licks, lies at your feet purring; lions roar, cats chase shadows and watch over sleeping humans; may fly into a rage if treated badly and lash out at anyone).

The obvious solution to the second section (3 verses) is

> RIDDLE (neat, fun to guess, warms the heart; sometimes hated, downvoted, commented on, and closed).

Now putting these together, I wonder if we should use the fact that

> CAT is the subject of a long-running RIDDLERS' meme here on PSE, often associated with riddles whose titles contain the word "pray":
>
>  [You will have to pray!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4615/5373)
>  [riddle - pray you can find the word!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5141/5373)
>  [Riddle... pray that this is the last one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5428/5373)

So perhaps the real intended answer is

> PRAY.

Comment: This answer blew me away. Points for making me wish I was ever this clever.

Comment: @user1566694 I guess the era of meta-riddles is over these days :-)